# Hidden objects when "Apply Model Changes to Database"

Tags: powerdesigner

PowerDesigner 16.5.4.0 (4521)
When I "Apply Model Changes to Database" after making an appropriate table selection I get this message: 
Some select objects are no longer visible in the select page
due to a filter. You can choose to:
Select only the displayed objects.
Keep the hidden objects in the selection.

Question #1: what/where is the " filter' they reference??
Question #2: How can I view the "hidden" objects, so I can I make a determination of "what to do" with these objects??

Thanks
Murray Sobol
Openlink Agribusiness Solutions

Comment: The "filter" is the one which limits the displayed objects. Maybe it is the "table selection" you mentioned. As with all objects lists, you have a "Enable/disable filter" on the toolbar; I guess it is pushed as the filter is enabled; you can try to de-select it to show all objects.

Comment: I guess that before selecting the objects that interest you and that you want generated in the database, you should deselect all objects using the `Deselect All>All Pages` button in the toolbar.